# Какие элементы являются сестринскими

Tags: html, теория

Предположим, есть структура:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <em></em>
  </li>
  <li>
    <em></em>
  </li>
</ul>
```

В ней:
`<ul>` - родительский элемент для всех `<li>` и `<em>`.
`<li>` - дочерние элементы по отношению к `<ul>`, родительские по отношению к `<em>` и в то же время сестринские.
Однако можно ли также считать элементы `<em>` сестринскими, ведь они имеют общего родителя и находятся на одинаковом уровне вложенности?

Comment: ну я бы не считал все em сестринскими. на английском языке такие элементы еще называют siblings (дети одних родителей). но у них разные родители li, поэтому они не сестринские

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Родителем и потомком называют те элементы, разница между которыми один уровень. Если разница между элементами несколько уровней, например, ul и em, то такие элементы называют предок (ul) и потомок (em).

То есть для em родитель только li, соответственно если у конкретно этого li есть дети, то только они будут сестринскими к em.